# A way to change Names of app between Development and prod

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way in iOS to have an app to have different names for different bundle id? Like `X` and the other `X DEV`. I know a way to install them along side Eachother but if I can have different names or Icon that would be super Helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second target in Xcode and you can set an alternate name, bundle id, and icon.